# How to add grid lines to display form of a list item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, splistitem, display-form

I am trying to figure out how to make my display item form look like a table. I am using SharePoint 2013, and currently, the display form can be a bit difficult to read without lines separating fields. I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm not sure if it is a good idea from a user experience point of view to add a separator between each and every field.

Instead if the amount of fields are fixed on the list/app in question I would rather apply kind of grouping by only adding a separator after a logical group of fields, but that's an advanced task.

However here's a piece of CSS to add a line between each field of a standard SharePoint input form:

```
#onetIDListForm .ms-formtable .ms-formlabel,
#onetIDListForm .ms-formtable .ms-formbody
{
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a list look more like a table simply select the list:

1. Click on the Library tab on top and select "Modify View"
2. Scroll down until you find "Style".
3. Click to expand it and select the style you want! Basic Table might do it for you or Shaded which improves readability a lot!

In case you just need a table, simply Edit the page:

1. Select the Insert tab and select "Table", to insert a table
2. After you insert the desired table, you can edit it through the Design tab that appears when you select your table in Edit mode. (Make the grid lines visible or not, etc)